# Making a topologie map/groupby/count, the store is empty

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I dont understand why the store "statStore" is empty in that topology :

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KTable<String, PersonAvro> person$ = builder.table("sc_loc_person_priv_v4");
    person$.mapValues(person -> CustomerAvro.newBuilder()
            .setId(person.getId())
            .setCompName(person.getCompName())
            .setSiretCode(person.getSiretCode())
            .setActive(person.getActive())
            .setAdd3(person.getAdd3())
            .setAdd4(person.getAdd4())
            .setAdd5(person.getAdd5())
            .setAdd6(person.getAdd6())
            .setAdd7(person.getAdd7()))
            .mapValues(CustomerAvro.Builder::build)
            .toStream()
            .peek((key, personne) -> {
                journal.debug("{}, {}", key, personne);
            })
            .through("sc_loc_customer_priv_v1")
            .groupBy((String key, CustomerAvro customer) -> customer.getActive())
            .count(Materialized.as("statStore"));
    Topology topology = builder.build();
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
    streams.start();
    store = waitUntilStoreIsQueryable("statStore", streams);
```

Naturaly, i putted messages in the topic sc_loc_person_priv_v4.

If i simply do that topology, the store is not empty:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() throws InterruptedException {
    configurer();
    producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    builder.globalTable(kafkaTopic, Materialized.as("customerStore"));
    Topology topology = builder.build();
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
    streams.start();
    store = waitUntilStoreIsQueryable("customerStore", streams);
}

public long getNb() {
    return store.approximateNumEntries();
}
```

Comment: What is `kafkaTopic` -- in the first example there are two topics? Do you have data in "sc_loc_customer_priv_v1" ?

Comment: Sorry, kafkaTopic="sc_loc_person_priv_v4". I putted the value instead of the variable in the first example to simplify but I forgot the second example.

Comment: Did  you check if there is data written into `sc_loc_customer_priv_v1`? Can `customer.getActive()` return `null` -- those messages would get dropped.